# Powershell Import-Csv Trying to convert a CSV file to HTML but I can't figure out how to add the ID parameter to the table (needed for a jscript)

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, import-csv

```
$bodyformat += 
 '<input type="text" id="search_field_input" onkeyup="search_table()" placeholder="Type to search">'
$bodyformat += 
 '<script>
  function search_table(){
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search_field_input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table_id");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td") ; 
  for(j=0 ; j<td.length ; j++)
  {
  let tdata = td[j] ;
  if (tdata) {
    if (tdata.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      break ; 
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
   } 
  }
 }
}
</script>'
```

$html = Import-Csv -delimiter ',' -Path D:\Temp\final.csv | Foreach {$*.link= '{1}' -f $*.Link,$*.Title;$*} |
Select ID,Link | ConvertTo-Html  -Head $htmlformat -Body $bodyformat

$html -replace "<","<" -replace """,'"' -replace ">",">" | Out-File D:\Outbound\index.html

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't use `$_.link` etc in your script block?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by, "how to add the ID parameter to the table?" Maybe show an example of what you are seeing and what you would like to see?